# root folder error on 20.04 LTS desktop after installing Ubuntu

Tags: boot, software-installation

I had fan problem and overheat tendency in my laptop. So I realized my problem started after installing win10. I didn’t want to go back to win7 so I opted to use Ubuntu. I downloaded and burned the iso file to a 8gig usb stick. I decided to do a clean install. At the end of installation, it requested to restart. After hitting enter, I removed the usb stick but it didn’t restart instead showed a number of codes along the lines of

```
buffer i/o error on dev sda
```

But I forced shut down. I turned it on again but this time, an error code

```
/dev/mapper/vgubunt-root: clean, 158774/15171584 files, 2587925/60662784 blocks
```

Early this morning when turned it on, no problem. I even did a little browsing and edited on documents, then turned it off again, thinking it is all well. Now I turn it on, it back but this screen below
[image]

It does not seem to change. Been like that for almost 5 min.

Comment: Please post the full error messages (at least, post a photo of that, since you cannot copy-paste them). Otherwise, we cannot do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for being there. My solution was to change hard disk and the problem has been solved.